# How to make a checkbox act like a radio button while clicking o divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need to make a checkbox to act as a radio button here in the below code you can see when clicking on the div it adds a selected and my checkbox is checked but when I click on another div it adds a selected class and checkbox is checked. As you can see my previous divs checkbox is still checked someone please help me.

```js
<script>
$('.js-single-select-img').click(function() {
   $('.js-single-select-img').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   $(this).find('input[name="single-select"]').prop('checked', true);
 });
</script>
```

```css
.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.js-single-select-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
   <div class="position-absolute top-right">
      <input type="checkbox" name="single-select" class="css-control-input"  value="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
   <div class="position-absolute top-right">
      <input type="checkbox" name="single-select" class="css-control-input"  value="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the class **selected** from all by limiting the `this` with the `not()` method, indicating here the addition of this class to the `this`.

By *analogy*, we display a check mark in a checkbox using the `find()` method, finding the checkbox of the current parent.

```js
$(".js-single-select-img").click(function () {
    $(".js-single-select-img").removeClass("selected").not($(this).addClass("selected"));
    $('input[name="single-select"]').prop("checked", false).not($(this).find('input[name="single-select"]').prop("checked", true));
});
```

```css
.position-relative {
    position: relative;
}

.position-absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.top-right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.selected {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.js-single-select-img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
    <div class="position-absolute top-right">
        <input type="checkbox" name="single-select" class="css-control-input" value="1" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
    <div class="position-absolute top-right">
        <input type="checkbox" name="single-select" class="css-control-input" value="1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the desired outcome is to only allow a single option to be selected - thgen the correct type of input IS the `radio` - so simply changing the input types should allow this.**

Always use the correct tool for the job - the single role of the checkbox is to allow 1 or more options to be selected. The radio can only allow 1 iinput at a time to be selected / checked.

As can be seen - clicking one will set it to active and apply the styling and checked state - then clicking the other will set that one to active.

Note that radio buttons MUST share the same name for the inputs - allowing only one value for the group on same named inputs.

```js
$('.js-single-select-img').click(function() {
   $('.js-single-select-img').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   $(this).find('input[name="single-select"]').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

```css
.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.js-single-select-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
   <div class="position-absolute top-right">
      <input type="radio" name="single-select" class="css-control-input"  value="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="position-relative js-single-select-img">
   <div class="position-absolute top-right">
      <input type="radio" name="single-select" class="css-control-input"  value="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed your goal very close

```
$('.js-single-select-img').click(function() {
      $('.js-single-select-img').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

   //---- Added new lines ---- Start
   //Find the parent element for all checkboxes
   let containerElement = $(this).parent();
   //find all desired checkboxes within parent element
   $(containerElement).find("input[class='css-control-input']").each(function() {
     //And deselect all
     $(this).removeProp('checked');
   });
   //---- Added new lines ---- End

   //Select the current checkbox
   $(this).find('input[name="single-select"]').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

As @gavgrif mentionend, don't abuse checkboxes for that, use radio boxes instead. You can also change the style of radioboxes with css so they looks like checkboxes.

Comment: Do not use `removeProp` on native properties like `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled`.  https://api.jquery.com/removeprop/